# How to install "vinelab/http" in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5

I am following the documentation at 
https://packagist.org/packages/vinelab/http

My composer.json :

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
        "vinelab/http": "dev-master" 
    },
```

my app.php in config

```
'providers' => [

...       
        /*
         * Helpers from packalyst.com
         */
        Vinelab\Http\HttpServiceProvider::class

    ],

    'aliases' => [

...
        /*
         * Helpers from packalyst.com
         */
        cURL'      =>  Vinelab\Http\Facades\Client::class

    ],
```

Following all the steps diligently.
I run php composer update and get this error.
http://goo.gl/sOj2gG

I am a novice in laravel and composer and am learning my way through.
Thank you for the help guys !

Comment: Can you check vendor directory vinelab/http folder for make sure composer install this packge.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have Zjango package in your service provider, but your composer.json file doesn't seem to show it. It is trying to load a service provider that hasn't been loaded via composer.json.

try adding `"zjango/laracurl": "dev-master"` to your composer.json file and run composer update again.

Comment: Let me update the screenshot. I did that and pasted the wrong screenshot. 
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
        "vinelab/http": "dev-master" 
    },

Comment: Made the changes and ran composer update. But still same error. .
Updated the error image in the question too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the composer package before putting in the service provider.

1. Remove the provider from the array in `config/app.php`.
2. Run `composer update`.
3. Put the provider back into the array in `config/app.php`.